# How do I increase the font size of a different components element using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

So I am trying to increase the font size of the paragraph element in the content.jsx file using the button with the onClick of handleFontSize in the header.jsx. Right now my issue is that the increaseFont function in App.jsx is not working correctly. It is only staying at 12 each time I click the button. I want it to go up two font sizes each time so it would make the fontSize 12px(default) then 14px then 16px and so on.

Header.jsx file

```
import React from "react"; react

function Header ({ loggedIn, handleLoggedInClick, handleFontSize }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLoggedInClick}>
        {loggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In"}
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleFontSize}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Content.jsx file

```
import React from "react";

function Content ({ loggedIn, fontSize }) {
  return loggedIn && <p style={{fontSize:{fontSize}}}>CONTENT</p>;
}

export default Content;
```

App.jsx file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Content from "./Content";
import Header from "./Header";

function App () {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [newFontSize, setFontSize] = useState(12);
  const toggleLoggedIn = () => setLoggedIn(!loggedIn);
  
  const increaseFont = () => setFontSize(newFontSize + 2)
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Header loggedIn={loggedIn} handleLoggedInClick={toggleLoggedIn} />
      <Content loggedIn={loggedIn} handleFontSize={increaseFont} fontSize={newFontSize} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please read the advice in [ask], in particular the bit about *not* providing *pictures* of text.

Comment: I get your question, and i saw where the code is wrong. may you please copy and paste the code here for three files i will edit it for you

Comment: @CrispenGari Great, thank you! I edited the question to include the code for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Content from "./Content";
import Header from "./Header";

function App () {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [newFontSize, setFontSize] = useState(12);
  const toggleLoggedIn = () => setLoggedIn(!loggedIn);
  
  const increaseFont = () => setFontSize(newFontSize + 2)
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Header loggedIn={loggedIn} handleLoggedInClick={toggleLoggedIn} handleFontSize={increaseFont}  />
      <Content loggedIn={loggedIn} fontSize={newFontSize} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Content.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Content ({ loggedIn, fontSize }) {
  return loggedIn && <p style={{fontSize:fontSize}}>CONTENT</p>;
}

export default Content;
```

Header.jsx

```
import React from "react"; react

function Header ({ loggedIn, handleLoggedInClick, handleFontSize }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLoggedInClick}>
        {loggedIn ? "Log Out" : "Log In"}
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleFontSize}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Try this and let me know if it works, i only edited the first two files

Comment: Please do explain in your answer what you actually change and why it works instead of just providing the correct snippet  like @VoQuocThang has done in his answer

Comment: You passed `handleFontSize` prop to the wrong component, it should be header not content.jsx the property `fontSize` under styles should be a value not an object. otherwise everything is okay

Answer (score 0):

You're passing handleFontSize to the wrong component.It should be passed to Header component

```
   <div>
      <Header loggedIn={loggedIn} handleLoggedInClick={toggleLoggedIn} handleFontSize={increaseFont} />
      <Content loggedIn={loggedIn} fontSize={newFontSize} />
    </div>
```

Comment: May you please vote for my answers, please

Comment: @CrispenGari it should be voluntarily